# Best library to render tables?

Tags: charts

I'm wondering if there is a library or package that can help me render beautiful tables / grid reports?  I'm referring to libraries like High Charts & Fusion Charts, all of which have great chart rendering engines.  But I can't find any that renders tables and grids. Any help / ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which technology you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#tables) to make a web site. The way that is manage the table is elegant.

This may be of you help